# Direct Connect P2P libraries for linking iPhone, Android, and .net desktop apps

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, android, p2p

Currently my users connect to their computer from their phone via a asynchronous TCP connections, but this requires them to open a specific port, and to have to know their IP address. Then there's the problem of dynamic IP addresses, and it all becomes just too much.

I'd like for them to not have to mess with any of this. And after a bit of searching I've realized what I really need is a Direct Connect p2p connection between the two.

I'd like to implement this, but what do I need? The server running on the user's computer is .NET and the clients are running Android and iPhone.

Comment: You use the phrase 'p2p' in your question without really describing what you mean. Can you clarify please? I know it stands for "point to point", but what do you actually mean by that?

Comment: Essentially, direct connect p2p, is when one or more clients talks to a publicly available third party with an open port. Clients behind NAT can only receive incoming connections from server/port that they made an outgoing connection to, unless of course they have an open port assigned to them. In the case of direct connect p2p, the third party accepts the connections from the 2 clients you're trying to connect, and it forwards the data to each one. So now the clients behind NAT know the server and port that have been opened by the original outgoing connection and they can communicate directly

Comment: So you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28file_sharing%29 I'd add that link to your question, it would clarify it greatly

Comment: I actually think it'll muddy the waters a bit, as that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. That link talks about file sharing and peer-to-peer, when I'm merely trying to connect to clients behind NAT to one another without requiring a user to open a port on their firewall. If a person doesn't know what a direct p2p connection is when reading this question, and they need a link in order to understand it, then how exactly are they qualified to answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

As one of the options, you can check our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) product. It lets you easily exchange messages between various platforms, including iPhone, Java-based systems and .NET.

Comment: You are aware that answering tons of questions with "buy our product" and no other content may be considered spam here, right?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic IP addressing doesn't have to be such a pain -- you can use a service such as http://www.dyndns.com/ to have a given network name map to the actual IP, which can be dynamic.

As for not opening the user's firewall -- without knowing more about the nature of your software/problem, it's hard to say. But if you're wanting a direct connection from phone to user's home computer, without any third party device/service involved, you don't have much choice but to accept that the computer has to be able to accept incoming connections.

If you accept the possibility of a third party in the communication, that can offer some possibilities, depending on what your software does. But it also adds lots of complexity.

Comment: I do want a direct connection with a third party device. That's what I'm looking to setup, what I'm asking specifically is what I need, what I need on the server and what libraries are available for iOS, Android, and C# so that I can facilitate this.

Comment: Ok I see. That wasn't very clear from your question. I wasn't sure from your non-capitalisation of direct connect if you meant just a direct connection, or some sort of specific protocol. Consider editing your question to make it a little clearer and giving it a better title, e.g. "Direct Connect P2P libraries for linking iPhone/Android/.net desktop"